# Query based on more than 1 field

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

not sure how to title this but here is my scenario

working on Webmatrix, built in sqlCE DB.

Have a table with multiple bit fields (3 fields)

what i need is to search for all records but skip those where any one of these three bit fields is False

my query looks like this

```
Select * From Tr where Tr.ClID=28 and (VApproved<>'False' or PApproved<>'False' or CApproved<>'False')
```

Now if i search for ClID=28 i get 7 records and with the above query also get 7 records.  Se basically the second part of the where condition is not working.

Appreciate your help and assistance.

Thanks,

Addition
Data Looks like this

```
ClID    VApproved    PApproved    CApproved
****    *********    *********    *********
28      True         True         True
28      True         True         True
28      NULL         True         True
28      NULL         True         True
28      NULL         True         True
28      NULL         True         True
28      NULL         False        True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to skip any with `False` value, then you it's just your condition that isn't correct, it should be:

`Select * From Tr where Tr.ClID=28 and VApproved<>'False' and PApproved<>'False' and CApproved<>'False'`

i.e. all of them must not be false, so we use `AND` not `OR`. And considering your NULL requirement it should be like this:

`Select * From Tr where Tr.ClID=28 and (VApproved=1 OR VApproved IS NULL) and (PApproved=1 OR PApproved IS NULL) and (CApproved=1 OR PApproved IS NULL)`

Comment: that will skip all the NULL values which i do not wish to ignore, what i mean is, we know there are 7 records, and only 2 of them has all bit fields as True.  that is what will be returned with the above query, and it will skip all the other fields.

Comment: @cjv do you wish to treat `NULL`s as `False` or `True`?

Comment: logically considered as true.

Comment: @cjv could you also please post all 7 rows of data, current and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have the condition wrong. This:

```
and (VApproved<>'False' or PApproved<>'False' or CApproved<>'False')
```

says to get rows where any (or all) of the fields is not false, meaning a row with some (or all) true will be a match. You probably want this:

```
(coalesce(VApproved,1) & coalesce(PApproved,1) & coalesce(CApproved,1)) = 1
```

Using `bitwise logical and` `&` together with coalesce() makes sure only rows where all columns are true or null are returned. This will return all rows in your sample data except the row where PApproved is False.

If you just want the rows with all true values (treating null as false) then:

```
where (VApproved & PApproved & CApproved) = 1
```

will do it. This will return just the first two rows in the sample.

Comment: some problem with the isnull syntax

Comment: What problem with isnull?

Comment: err msg is : The number of arguments specified for the function is not correct. [ Minimum argument count = 1, Maximum argument count = 1,Name of function(if known) = isnull ]

Comment: Oh, apparently isnull is not implemented in sqlce, but coalesce is, try that instead.

Comment: same error, says coalesce takes zero arguments  The number of arguments specified for the function is not correct. [ Minimum argument count = 0, Maximum argument count = 0,Name of function(if known) = coalesce ]

Comment: According to the online documentation it should work: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174075%28v=sql.110%29.aspx but maybe you are using an older version (capabilities have improved over time). Anyway, never mind as you already got a working answer :)

Comment: hello @jpw, thank you for your effort to assist me.  Much appreciate it.  am using WebMatrix 2.